# Spyder started launching separate Python application for each console

Tags: python, macos, console, anaconda, spyder

I'm running Anaconda Navigator 1.10.0 on Mohave with Spyder 4.1.5.
I've notice in the past week for every console (kernel) I am running, it launches a separate Python app.  It's annoying when running multiple consoles and using 'Command + tab' to cycle through apps. I've attached a screenshot showing 'Command + tab' with three consoles running in Spyder.

How do I get rid of these white python icons?

> Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 15:01:53)
> Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> IPython 7.16.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a Spyder preference setting, but it's actually caused by newer version of matplotlib.

The following prevents multiple Spyder/Python icons appearing in the mac dock:

> Use only the IPython inline backend, which can be selected in:
> Spyder > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics backend

Pulled from:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1645